Subscribe to Tiktok's "new lead" webhook
We're trying to integrate our CRM with TikTok lead ads and I fail to find any documentation regarding how to subscribe to the relevant webhook to get new-lead notifications in the real time.
The TikTok developer portal claims TikTok do have solution for TikTok Custom API with Webhooks, but I fail to find any technical documentation for it.
Did anyone try to build a custom integration with TikTok lead ads?
Did anyone succeed?
Thanks in Advance,
Michael

Webhook Subscription documentation - https://business-api.tiktok.com/portal/docs?id=1738964126095362
P.S. Make sure you have granted access to Lead Management in your dev app's permissions area.
